# Retrieving object directly using objectId stopped working after parse migration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I have migrated data from .bson file to our mongodb database. I used following command to restore database from bson file which is I downloaded from parse.com

mongorestore --drop -d db_name -c collection_name path/file.bson

Updating score using objectId stopped working after parse migration. It was working fine on parse.com. I am using following url to get score

http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore/2ntvSpRGIK where 2ntvSpRGIK is objectId

If I try using another field like say userName I am able to get score successfully for same user which has objectId 2ntvSpRGIK but not able to update it using objectId as I am getting 404 error in the http callback function.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a separate UserScore class you're trying to access? Because you mention that a couple of times. Your question is not very clear at all. You didn't provide any context. You didn't provide any of your configurations for how your server is set up. Add a lot more info, or nobody will be able to help here.

Comment: I have only one class named GameScore and I am running server on localhost

Comment: You haven't shown how you're trying to update this object. And why are you using a straight up URL instead of one of many SDKs?